# Python - Replace x linhas acima e abaixo do texto procurado

Tags: python, replace

Boas,

Precisava de fazer algo que num documento preenchido por exemplo como:

```
linha1 bla bla
linha2 bla bla
linha3 bla bla
linha4 bla bla
linha5 bla bla
linha6 bla blax
linha7 bla bla
linha8 bla bla
linha9 bla bla
```

Ao fazer um search por blax ele remove as 3 linhas anteriores e as 2 linhas seguintes, colocando no mesmo sitio Linha10 blaaaaaa

Eu ja tenho o find a funcionar, nao sei é como implementar esta regra.

Alguem tem alguma ideia?

Em baixo o meu Find:

```
def find():
    textarea.tag_remove('found', '1.0', END)
    s = edit.get()
    if s:
        idx = '1.0'
        while 1:
            idx = textarea.search(s, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=END)
            if not idx: break
            lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))
            textarea.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
            idx = lastidx
        textarea.tag_config('found', foreground='red')
    edit.focus_set()
```

Answer (score 0):

O complicado é tentar fazer isso usando as funções do tkinter que são horríveis. Se possível extrai o texto e usa funções python - por exemplo regex:

```
result = re.sub(r'(?:^.+?$\n){3}^.*blax.*$\n(?:^.+?$\n){2}', 
    'Linha10 blaaaaaaa\n', texto, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```